# CNN for recognizing five different faces

Tags: neural-network, keras, lasagne

I have a project for face recognition of five people that I want my CNN to detect, and I was wondering if people could have a look at my model to see if this is a step in the right direction

```
def model():

    model= Sequential()

    # sort out the input layer later
    model.add(convolutional.Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation='relu'), input_shape=(3,800,800))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(convolutional.Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(convolutional.MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    flatten()

    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(p=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(number_of_faces, activation='softmax'))
```

so the model will be taking in pictures (headshots found on google of 5 people) in 3 channels of size 800 by 800 with 64 feature maps, pooled and then another set of feature maps
and then connected to a mlp for classification into a binary vector for 5 output neurons.  My question is, is this a decent approach to try and classify headshots of certain people?
for example if I were to download one hundred pictures of a certain person and put them through this model, would the feature space created in the convolution be big enough to capture
the features of that face and four others?
thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not an engineering issue but a scientific one. It is hard to judge whether 100 picture is enough for your purpose without showing current progress (like, what is the accuracy now? Are your facing overfitting or underfitting.

But, **YES**, extra data of faces can help with your model, especially when those faces are of same context (background, light, angle, skin color, etc.) with your eventual testing data.

If you are interesting in face recognition, you can start with [*Deep Learning Face Representation from Predicting 10,000 Classes*](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/pdf/YiSun_CVPR14.pdf) (unofficial [code here](https://github.com/stdcoutzyx/DeepID_FaceClassify)), they use 10 thousand faces as extra dataset to train. You can search "DeepID" for more information.

If you are an engineering guy, you can check *[Facial Expression Recognition with Convolutional Neural Networks](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports2016/023_Report.pdf)*, this report focus more on implementation, which is also implemented by Keras.

By then way, 800*800 is extra large in face recognition community. You might like to resize them to a smaller size. Otherwise your program might be too gargantuan to train and consumes butch of memory.

Comment: thank you thank you, i will take this on board, of course i can always resize and add more faces, but is the architecture of the network okay for five faces do you think? as in 2dconv with 64 filters etc etc

Comment: Glad that can help you. Your network is STANDARD, but I cannot ensure the performance of it. To be honest, the optimal structure of neural network still remains an enigma. So what we can do is to be patient with experiments and to refer more previous works. From that perspective, your network is STANDARD.

Comment: thanks man, Van, what I am concerned about mainly however is even If I have headshots, it will have some background space, will the nextwork take care of this or do I need to supply input images of JUST the face and absolutely nothing else?

Comment: Almost any raw picture has background or irrelevant margins, therefore we first will use a "face detector" to crop face from pictures first. But that is another line of work. Your network should works on those cropped faces.

Comment: van for example these pictures will be fine, even though the actual face is pretty small part of picture? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=david+cameron&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB693GB693&espv=2&biw=1598&bih=908&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic_6-E6PrNAhVaOMAKHTiMCCIQ_AUICCgD

Comment: LOL. I think those are good to go. One of the most famous face dataset is [LFW](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/alpha_all_0.html), which you can take a look.

Comment: hey Van whats good my friend, just got it set up and now have passed three hundred pictures of cropped faces of two politicians, and am getting around 40% accuracy, so I was wondering what the steps are at first to fine tune models, and by the way this is off of around 350 faces each person

Answer (score 0):

Face recognition is not a regular classification study. If you train your model for 5 people, even if it would be a successful model, you need to re-train it if a new person join to the team. It means that your new model might not be successful anymore.

We firstly train a regular classification model but then drop its final softmax layer and use its early layer to represent images. Representations are multi-dimensional vector. Herein, we expect that image pair of same person should have high similarity whereas image pair of different persons should have low similarity. We can find the vector similarities with cosine similarity or euclidean distance methods.

To sum up, you should not train a model anymore for face recognition application. You just need to use a neural networks to predict. Predictions will be representations.

I recommend you to use deepface. It wraps state-of-the-art face recognition models such as VGG-Face, Google FaceNet, OpenFace, Facebook DeepFace, DeepID and Dlib. It also handles face detection and alignment in the background. You just need to call a line of code to apply face recognition.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib']
obj = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
print(obj["verified"], ", ", obj["distance"])
```

Returned object stores max threshold value and found distance. In this way, it returns True in verified param if the image pair is same person, returns False if the image pair is different persons.